# Do you know a jQuery plugin that have similar feature to this?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I saw a website that have cool step by step form registration, the website is here: http://planner.builtbybuffalo.com/step-1/

Do you know a jQuery plugin that can imitate the functionality of that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easiest I've read about (several times) is the [jQuery Form Wizard Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/formwizard).  Give that a try and see what you think.  See the [plugin's home page](http://thecodemine.org/#_demoForm=first) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This one is quite cool too!

[Fancy Sliding Form with jQuery](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/07/fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery/)

Not identical but you might consider it I guess.